# Appending rows to dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to union a row in an existing dataframe. 
I have an existing dataframe of the schema below :-

```
StructType(List(StructField(date,TimestampType,true),
               StructField(time,StringType,>true),
               StructField(size,IntegerType,true),
               StructField(r_version,StringType,true),
               StructField(r_arch,StringType,true),
               StructField(r_os,StringType,true),
               StructField(>package,StringType,true),
               StructField(version,StringType,true),
               StructField(country>,StringType,true),
               StructField(ip_id,IntegerType,true)))
```

I'm trying to append a row to it. But i'm facing error for the date field which is Timestamp type

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
d = lit('2015-12-12 00:00:00').cast("timestamp")
from pyspark.sql import Row
new = [ Row(d,'13:42:10',100,'3.2.3','i377','NA','','','DE','900') ]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(new,s)
```

Here s contains the schema.

the error i receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 522, in createDataFrame
rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 383, in _createFromLocal
data = list(data)
File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 505, in prepare
verify_func(obj, schema)
File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1360, in _verify_type
_verify_type(v, f.dataType, f.nullable)
File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1324, in _verify_type
raise TypeError("%s can not accept object %r in type %s" % (dataType, obj, 
type(obj)))
TypeError: TimestampType can not accept object Column<CAST(2015-12-12 
00:00:00 AS TIMESTAMP)> in type <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Parse the "date" column using dateparser, if you are specifying Timestamp in the schema upfront

2. In the schema define the "date" column as StringType and convert it using cast() during select

**Code for Option1:**

```
import time,datetime,dateparser
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, from_unixtime
from pyspark.sql import Row,Column
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, 
TimestampType,StringType,IntegerType

#d =  "2015-12-12 00:00:00" 
d0 =  dateparser.parse("2015-12-12 00:00:00")
t0 = int(time.mktime(d0.timetuple()))
print "dt0, ts0", d0, t0

schema= StructType([StructField("date",TimestampType(),True),  
           StructField("time",StringType(),True),   
           StructField("size",IntegerType(),True),  
           StructField("r_version",StringType(),True),  
           StructField("r_arch",StringType(),True), 
           StructField("r_os",StringType(),True),  
           StructField("rpackage",StringType(),True),  
           StructField("version",StringType(),True),  
           StructField("country",StringType(),True), 
           StructField("ip_id",IntegerType(),True)]) 


new = [ Row(d0,'13:42:10',100,'3.2.3','i377','NA','','','DE',900) ]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(new,schema) 
df2.show()
```

**Code for Option2:**

```
# have "date" as StringType instead of TimestampType when creating the 
# dataframe
df2.select(df2.date.cast("timestamp").alias("date_col_ts")).show()
```

Comment: I get an error at dateparser & im not able to install it. Im using python 2.7

Comment: What is the error? You can also use the datetime,time packages as well to do the same thing (casting).